# Problem in Creating Antlr4 Compiler in JavaScript: Unexpected Output when Transforming JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, antlr4

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/dailyjs/compiler-in-javascript-using-antlr-9ec53fd2780f) which describes how to create a JavaScript Compiler for a ANTLR4 grammar (ECMAScript.g4). As an example, it also describes how to transform something from JavaScript to Python using visit(), visitChildren(), visitTerminal(), and visitErrorNode() methods implemented using functions of the ECMAScriptVisitor.js file.

For this, an expression `{x: 1}` is given as the input from JavaScript where the output should be `{'x': 1}` to match the Python-accepted format of expressions.

Everything worked fine till I ran the program where I got the below output:

[image]

What might be the reason for this error to appear? [This is the link](https://github.com/SharkJ/My-JScript-Compiler-for-ANTLR4.git) to the github repo where I have uploaded the part of the project I've completed so far. Here's the index.js:

```
const antlr4 = require('antlr4');
const ECMAScriptLexer = require('./lib/ECMAScriptLexer.js');
const ECMAScriptParser = require('./lib/ECMAScriptParser.js');
const PythonGenerator = require('./codegeneration/PythonGenerator.js');

const input = '{x: 1}';

const chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
const lexer = new ECMAScriptLexer.ECMAScriptLexer(chars);

lexer.strictMode = false; // do not use js strictMode

const tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
const parser = new ECMAScriptParser.ECMAScriptParser(tokens);
const tree = parser.program();

console.log('JavaScript input:');
console.log(input);
console.log('Python output:');

const output = new PythonGenerator().start(tree);

console.log(output);
```

And here's PythonGenerator.js:

```
const ECMAScriptVisitor = require('../lib/ECMAScriptVisitor').ECMAScriptVisitor;

class Visitor extends ECMAScriptVisitor {
  start(ctx) {
    return this.visitExpressionSequence(ctx);
  }

visitChildren(ctx) {
  let code = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
    code += this.visit(ctx.getChild(i));
  }

  return code.trim();
}

visitTerminal(ctx) {
  return ctx.getText();
}

visitPropertyExpressionAssignment(ctx) {
  const key = this.visit(ctx.propertyName());
  const value = this.visit(ctx.singleExpression());

  return `'${key}': ${value}`;
}

}
module.exports = Visitor;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As in your other question, please include the relevant code in the question itself, not as a link (especially not one to an entire project or one that can (and did) change). Also: I assume you're only asking why the output contains `<EOF>` at the end, not about the other differences to your expected output (the missing quotes and space) - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, by replacing the `const tree = parser.program();` statement in `index.js` by `const tree = parser.expressionSequence();` the problem is solved.

Comment: That's probably not the proper solution. Generally speaking, you *want* the rule to be anchored at EOF (I'm assuming here that `program` is simply defined as `expressionSequence EOF`), you just don't want to print it. By using the rule without `EOF`, you will silently abort the parse when running into a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing of note is that you call `start` with a  `ProgContext` object and then call `visitExpressionSequence` on it. This does not actually make a difference in this case because you override neither `vistExpressionSequence` nor `visitProg`, so both actually default to just calling `visitChildren`, so it makes no difference which one you call. Still, you should really only ever call `visit` explicitly, not any of the `visitFoo` methods. `visit` will then always make sure that the correct `visitFoo` method is called.

Moving on to the actual issue, you've got two problems: First the key in your output does not have quotes around it even though your `visitPropertyExpressionAssignment` method should accomplish exactly that. And secondly there's an `<EOF>` at the end of the output, which I assume you do not want.

The first problem is because your input produces a syntax error when parsed. This is because `{x: 1}` is not actually a valid JavaScript program because a `{` at the beginning of a statement is seen as the start of a block, not an object literal. You'd need to put parentheses around the literal to make it valid at the beginning of a statement.

The second problem is because the `prog` rule is terminated by the end of file, producing an `EOF` token. To avoid printing that, you can simply override `visitProg` to only call `visit` on its statement list and not on the `EOF` token.

You've fixed the first problem by only invoking the `expressionSequence` rule in your parser instead of `prog`. If to parse an expression instead of a program, that's fine (though in a REPL-like context, you might instead want to try to parse the input as an expression and, if that fails, parse it as a statement). Doing so may seem like it also fixes your second problem, but that's not quite the case:

You no longer get an `<EOF>` in the output because you no longer match the end of file. What this means is that if the input consists of a valid expression, followed by total garbage (say `const input = '{x: 1} krgsfkjhwruei';`), this will not cause a syntax error, but instead happily parse the `{x: 1}` part and then completely ignore the garbage part without any indication of a problem. That's almost never what you want. Instead you could define a new rule in your grammar that matches an expression, followed by the end of file, like this:

```
expressionInput: expressionSequence EOF;
```

Now if the input contains garbage after a valid expression, you'd get a syntax error. However this will re-introduce the problem of the `<EOF>` in the output. But again, you can just fix that by overriding `visitExpressionInput` and then only calling `visit(ctx.expressionSequence);`.